# Does using pandas.factorize retain the ordinal nature of a variable?

Tags: pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have a set of strings in a column for which I have derived the numerical value using pandas.factorize. But after conversion, I noticed that the dtype of the column is int.

The strings in the column are ordinal in nature and hence the numbers should represent an order instead of just being specified as int. Should i convert the numeric column into category using 'as.type' or can i feed the column into my machine learning model without converting into category?

Example: [T0, T1, T2] represent severity of cancer. After factorizing the result is [0,1,2]. But I am doubtful whether it establishes the relationship 0<1<2

Comment: in the latest version of pandas, "the parameter has no effect and has been deprecated"

Comment: Think you got lucky in this instance... default behaviour seems to be alphabetical..?

Comment: Alphabetical and in some cases alphanumeric. However, factorize is able to identify the order in both cases. I did consider using categorical but some columns have around 10-15 levels. I assumed factorizing and then converting into category would be an efficient way to code instead of specifying levels

Answer (score 1):

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
data['A'].astype(CategoricalDtype(ordered = True))
```

This created order after factorizing the categorical variable

Comment: How is astype(CategoricalDtype) different from Categorical() and from factorize()?